# Classpath variable 'JRE_LIB' in project is deprecated: Use the JRE System Library instead

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver

Attempting to Maven Clean the automation project displays the message "Could not find the main class. Program will exit"

After displaying the warnings of the project "Classpath variable 'JRE_LIB' in project 'ercard' is deprecated: Use the JRE System Library instead"

I'm starting in Java, and I don't know how to solve it.